# What is the probability of rolling exactly 2 2's when rolling 5 dice?

Tags: probability

I'm wondering if the probability is as simple as

$\frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{6} * \frac{5}{6} * \frac{5}{6} * \frac{5}{6}$, but I have no idea how to check my answer. (Order does not matter)

Comment: times $5\choose 2$ as any two of the five dices may show the 2s.

Comment: Are the dice distinguishable? I mean is $(2,2,3,4,5)$ and $(3,2,4,2,5)$ different?

Comment: No, the order does not matter.

Comment: @Mechy in that case your answer is correct, you do not need to multiply with $\binom{5}{2}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen read above.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: the probability of rolling two $2$s is $\binom{5}{2}\left(\frac16\right)^2\left(\frac56\right)^3$. It doesn't change just because we don't care about the order.

Comment: @robjohn but the OP clarified that to him order doesn't matter. Now I don't know *why* he would consider that, but that's what he said. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @robjohn also in that case, would you undelete the answer recently posted? My comment seems to have motivated the poster to delete it.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: if we wanted the first two dice to be $2$s, *then* the probability would be $\left(\frac16\right)^2\left(\frac56\right)^3$. The OP said that the order does not matter, so it would be the standard binomial distribution.

Comment: @robjohn ah yes I see. Thank you very much for correcting me.

Comment: Ah, good stuff. So basically permutations are easier than combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a binomial distribution. So:

$$P(X = 2) = \binom{5}{2} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2} \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{3}$$

We start by choosing our two die. Then the probability of getting the two $2$'s is $(\frac{1}{6})^{2}$. We multiply this by the probability of getting three die that are not $2$'s.

Comment: I have undeleted your answer because it is correct. If you still wish to delete, leave me a comment.

Comment: If everyone else thinks it's correct, I'm good with leaving it. Just didn't want to leave poor info. Thanks for the undelete! :-)